# angular 4: setting initial values from query params causes loop with onChange navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-changedetection

so to tell the story and where it breaks: I want to read the query parameters from the route and set the filter checkboxes with the intitial values accordingly. This does work with the code below (`ngOnInit`). The next thing I want to do is to update the route query parameters after a filter has been checked. This does also work with the code below (`filterChanged` + `navigate`).

And here comes the problem:

When I activate both parts, the initial values are set correctly, on selection/de-selection the events get fired and even the `navigate` Promise finishes, but the query parameters in the URL are not being updated.

I am happy for any help on this =)

Please see my coding below:

In my `sidebar.component` I am reading the query parameters from the route in the `onInit` like the following (subscribing to the routedata, and for every filter, read and set the queryParameters or initialize with `[]`) :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.filters = data[RouteData.filter]
      this.filters.forEach((filter: Filter) => {
        this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryMap => {
          const active = queryMap.getAll(filter.entity)
          this.activeFilters[filter.entity] = active ? active : []
        })
      })
    })
   }
```

So next up the `this.activeFilters` and `this.filters` are passed to a component containing checkboxes in the html:

```
    <filter *ngFor="let filter of filters"
            [filter]="filter"
            [active]="activeFilters[filter.entity]"
            (selection)="filterChanged(filter.entity, $event)">
    {{filter.label}}
    </filter>
```

So as soon as one of the checkboxes' value changes the whole current selection for that `filter.entity` gets emitted and navigated to afterwards.

```
filterChanged(entity: string, values: string[]) {
  this.activeFilters[entity] = values
  this.navigate()
}

navigate() {
  // gather parameters
  const queryParams = {}
  for (const filter of this.filters) {
    queryParams[filter.entity] = this.activeFilters[filter.entity]
  }
  this.router.navigate(
    [],
    {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: queryParams,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
  })
}
```

Comment: what happens if your try `this.router.navigate(['/'], ....)`

Comment: it navigates to the root of the application, meaning in this case away from the current path. Also including the same path in the commands field yields the same behaviour as before

Comment: in `navigate` if you console log `queryParams` is it correct? also if you try `this.router.navigate([''], ....)` what happens?

Comment: yes I did log queryParams, all as expected. also putting `this.router.navigate(...).then( () => console.log('done')` is executed, but the URL does not change. `this.router.navigate([''],..) ` does not change anything.

Comment: To mention it again: when I leave either part out, the other works perfectly fine. but the combination is giving me headaches. I do understand that there is a circular behaviour, but I would love to see the angular solution to it. I can't be the only one trying to achieve this =)